# Reading cookies using xcode on the iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, cookies, mobile-safari

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can an iPhone xcode application read cookies previously stored by Safari Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532117/can-an-iphone-xcode-application-read-cookies-previously-stored-by-safari-mobile)

I'm trying to read cookies using an xcode application im writing for iphone and testing on the emulator. However when I run the code below the value stored in numcookies is 0. Cookies are allowed via iphone settings and I also used mobile safari to navigate to gmail, hotmail and other cookie setting sites to increase cookie count on emulator, but no luck.

Your thoughts are much appreciated, really hope Im not doing something real silly :(

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *jar = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSInteger numcookies  = [[jar cookies] count];
```

tony