# ios - get cookies created by safari

Tags: ios, cookies

I'm creating a web page, when opened in iphone safari browser, a cookie will be created.
I am also creating iOS application in which it has to read the cookie created by my web page in safari browser.
Is it possible to read that cookie from my iOS application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531712/reading-cookies-using-xcode-on-the-iphone) we cannot access safari cookies.